# How to avoid publishing source code on shinyapps.io server?

Tags: r, shiny, rsconnect

On the shinyapps.io dashboard, you see an option to download bundle using which you can download source code to your app. So When I publish the app, can I avoid publishing this bundle on the app server or hide it?